# Getting tokenID from wallet address in ERC721

Tags: solidity, tokens, addresses, erc-721

I'm fairly new to solidity and especially token contracts, so please correct me if I'm missing something obvious.

I am currently working on my own implementation of `ERC721` token (using `ERC721URIStorage` too), and I'm thinking about the best way to get tokenID given a wallet address. Suppose a DApp is connected to user wallet, using the address I'd like to be able to query the tokenID so that I can perform other tokenID based queries and reads without reimplementing them all. Essentially I need a reverse `ownerOf()` function here. As far as I understand there is no function I can use in base openzeppelin implementation of ERC721 that could do that.

Is the best way to go just implementing my own function that'd access the `_owners` mapping of the base contract or is there a more elegant solution?